# How can I sort this array by Standard Sorting and not Natural Sorting?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$args = array('post_type'=>$post_type,'posts_per_page'=>-1, 'orderby' => 'number', 'order' => 'ASC',);
```

I posted a question here but think I made it too confusing.
[How can I order by a variable in this PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481282/how-can-i-order-by-a-variable-in-this-php-code)

Thanks for your help!

Here is a sample output.  The number, like the first 11, is in a "number" type field in ACF and the # is not part of the processing.

```
#11   Beyonce Bea   2019
#12   Haley Hanson   2019
#15   Cassidy Gardner   2019
#20   Brianna Phiakhamngon   2018
#21   Reed Hazard   2018
#24   Alyson Miura   2019
#31   Ciara James   2018
#32   Mollie Olson   2018
#45   Courtney Clemmer   2018
#5    Brooke Walling   2019
```

Comment: Please provide expected output for the sample input.

Comment: does the above help? http://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot